# Unable to change color of seek bar in Media Style notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have a music player application that uses media style notification for playback.
Recently android 10 added support of seek bar in media style notification, I was able to make functionality work using media session. But somehow I am not able to change the colour of that seekbar.

I am not really sure where notification is picking that black color though. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my style theme.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Changing color here did not help.

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for this problem?